# Hidden Field Value Blank Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf form which has 2 hidden fields. I specify the value of the hidden fields using th:value, and I bind these fields to an object.

```
<div class="w-row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        <div class="question_text_sc">
            <p th:text="${questionVO.questionText}" />
            <p th:text="${questionVO.questionStem}" />
            <p th:text="${sequenceNo}" />
            <p th:text="${quizID}" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="question_stem_sc"></div>
    <div class="w-col w-col-6">
        <div>
            <div class="w-form">
                <form class="w-clearfix" id="email-form" name="email-form" data-name="Email Form" action="#" th:action="@{/quiz/question}" th:object="${userResponseVO}" method="post">
                    <div th:each="option: ${questionVO.answerOptions}" class="w-radio radio_select" th:id="${'radio_1'}">
                        <input class="w-radio-input" id="radio" type="radio" name="answer_sc" th:field="*{answerID}" th:value="${option}"/>
                        <label class="w-form-label" id="answer_1" for="radio"><p th:text="${option}" /></label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="sequenceNo" th:field="*{sequenceNo}" th:value="${sequenceNo}" ></input>
                    <input type="hidden" name="quizID"  th:field="*{quizID}" th:value="${quizID}"></input>
                    <button class="button submit_answr" type="submit">Next Question</button>
                </form>
```

I want to bind the quizID and sequenceNo fields with the respective fields in the object. Line 6 and 7 correctly resolve the value of sequence number/quiz id and display it. However, the same value is not resolved in the th:value tag inside the form. The value is empty and nothing gets bound to the object fields.

[image: View Source]

Request your help here.

EDIT:

The code works when I remove the th:field attribute from the hidden element. But I want to bind it to an object variable, so that the server can process it. `

Comment: Are you sure that the class that backs `userResponseVO` has the properties `sequenceNo` and `quizID`?

Comment: Yes I am sure. And to test it, I have used in line 6 and 7. It is also shown in the "view source" image, as <p>6</p> and <p>1</p> respectively.

Comment: Would it be possible to share a sample of your project?

Comment: Why are you using both `th:value` and `th:field`? You should only be using `th:field` if the value belong to the object used in the form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me helped setting `th:field` (or actually `name`) using `th:attr`

```
th:value="${question.id}"
th:attr="name='questionIds[' + ${iter.index} + ']'"
```

In my example I wanted to have value from `${question}` but the target in input is `questionIDs[i]`

In simple problem like your `name=answerId` should be enough.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time and headache. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 21):

We can resolve your scenario in 2 ways

1st way:

```
<input type="hidden" th:value="${question.id}" th:attr="name='quizID'" />
```

2nd way:

```
<input type="hidden" th:value="${question.id}" name="quizID" />
```

If you used thymeleaf **th:field="*{sequenceNo}"**, internal code of thymeleaf works like,

- It will check is there any **name** attribute to particular element, if it is available **th:field value overrides on name attribute**.

  name="sequenceNo"
- It will check is there any **id** attribute to particular element, if it is not available with the name of **th:field value new attribute added on i.e)id**.

  id="sequenceNo"

Answer (score 0):

it seems Thymeleaf does not recognize the `hidden` fields. in order to fix it, try this:

1. define the input as text (not as hidden).
2. define an the style tag like `"display:none"` in order to hide the elements from the screen.

The result should be something like this:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{parameters[${stat.index}].field}" style="display:none;">
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have to collect a comment to a page. Then you must transmit to the controller, besides the comment, the name of the page. Ofcourse, the user don't have to re-enter the name of this page. This information must be passed to controller, but th:field only map the values entered by the user, not the values generated by default.
But you can transmit the name of this page to controller as parameter in URL.
In html, you have something like that:

```
<form  th:action="@{/saveComment(lastPage=${lastPage})}" th:object="${comments}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
 .................................................................................
            <h2>Enter your comment</h2>
            <textarea  th:field="${comments.comment}" rows="10" cols="100" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
            <label for="comment">Your comment here</label><br />
            <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form> 

In controller, you put stuff like this:

   @PostMapping("/saveComment")
    public String saveComment(Comments comments, String lastPage) {
        comments.setPage_commented(lastPage);
        commentsRepository.save(comments);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```