# Bind two hidden values in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a checkbox that is binding with two values at backend. My problem it is only binding one value and passing the other value as null aka my tmpltId. How can I bind two hidden values in Thymleaf and dont worry I have a getter and setter method in place. I just need to pass the value from the front. HELP!!!

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">

<li th:each="gcf : ${gcfs}">

<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{gcfId}" th:value="${gcf.gcfId}" th:text="${gcf.templateDesc}"/>
```

[My Code is similar to this but no one has given an answer for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808433/hidden-field-value-blank-thymeleaf)

Comment: th:field is telling processor which attribute of gfc object it is for. So you do not need th:value there. What do you mean bind? Can you be more specific, maybe example?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is away using `th:attr` 
who knew!

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html