# Thymeleaf: Pass data in hidden input field

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a submit button which passes data via the `@ModelAttribute`. However, the field values of `postDTO` in the `@PostController` are unchanged.

Many thanks and kind regards, Mike.

**Controller @GetMapping**

```
    @GetMapping("/post")
    public String post(Model model) {

    List<Post> posts = postRepository.findAllByOrderByPostedAtDesc();
    model.addAttribute("postDTO", new PostDTO("", ""));
    model.addAttribute("posts", posts);
    return "post";
}
```

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="post: ${posts}">
        <form th:if="${sessionUser!=null and sessionUser.admin == true}" th:object="${postDTO}" th:action="@{/postEdit}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" th:value="${post.id}">
            <button type="submit">Update post</button>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller @PostMapping**

```
@PostMapping("/postEdit")
public String editPost(@ModelAttribute("postDTO") PostDTO postDTO, @ModelAttribute("sessionUser") User sessionUser) {
    if (sessionUser.getAdmin()) {
        Optional<Post> post = postRepository.findById(postDTO.getId());
        if (post.isPresent()) {
            redirectAttributes.addAttribute("postId", post.get());
            return "redirect:/postEdit/";
        }
    }
    return "redirect:/post";
}
```

I already tried to modify my html form as suggested in [Hidden Field Value Blank Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808433/hidden-field-value-blank-thymeleaf). This works for the `postDTO`. However, my `sessionUser.id` is also set to the `post.id` value.

```
<form th:if="${sessionUser!=null and sessionUser.admin == true}" th:object="${postDTO}" th:action="@{/postEdit}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${post.id}">
    <button type="submit">Update post</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<script th:inline>` is the easiest way to setup hidden atributes through Thymeleaf.

**Here is a working example:**

```
<html>
 ...
 ...
<body>
    <span hidden id="myData"></span>
    ...
    ...
    <script th:inline="javascript">

        var myData = [[${modelAttributeValue}]];

        document.getElementById("myData").textContent = myData; 

    </script>
```

**Here is how the above example works:**

1. The hidden span element with id '**myData**' is defined above the script tag.
   This will create the empty span and keep it ready for use by the script.
2. The th:inline attribute of script will make Thymeleaf interpret it.
   Thymeleaf will set the value of variable 'myData' to the model attribute value   supplied by Java service.
3. The text content of span with id of 'myData' will be set to the value supplied by Java service, through the variable.

**More information:**

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart