# thymeleaf: th:value is ignored when using th:field

Tags: thymeleaf

I've got a form where I want to edit some user data.
So the already stored data is put as th:value and after sending I validate with spring validation and want to give back the form on wrong input. I want the input field to have the value of the input by the user but it always gives me the stored input instead.

That's how an input field looks like

```
<input type="text" th:value="${product.name}" th:field="*{name}" th:errorclass="fieldError"/>
```

If the form is loaded the first time the input fields should have the value of the already stored data.

If it's loaded after submit and with an validation error, the input fields should have the value of the user's input.

Is there a way to to that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using th:value? The answer to the last question is using th:field only, could you give it a try?

Comment: Cause I want to set the value when loading the stored data.

Comment: But if you are working with a form and populate the product object in your controller, that's going to work fine. Could you include the code of your form and your controller?

Answer (score 29):

Attribute **th:field** will replace attributes **value**, **id** and **name** in your **input** tag.

Instead, use plain **th:id**, **th:value** and **th:name** without using **th:field**. Then you will get what you wanted.

Then it will look like:

```
<input type="text" th:value="${product.name}" th:name="name" th:id="name" th:errorclass="fieldError"/>
```

Similar answer is here: [How to set thymeleaf th:field value from other variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027801/how-to-set-thymeleaf-thfield-value-from-other-variable)

Answer (score 3):

Because Attribute th:field is Combination of both th:name and th:value
So, either use this:

```
<input type="text" th:value="${product.name}" th:name="name" th:errorclass="fieldError"/>
```

Or this:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{name}" "th:errorclass="fieldError"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using th:field or value, id and name is ok. if you user th:field, you can write this：

```
<input type="text" th:field="${product.name}" th:value="${product.name}" "th:errorclass="fieldError"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your controller (you set wrong value to *{name}), if the input value is wrong after validation error.