# Spring boot model attribute changes unexpecedtly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring-boot Java application with Thymeleaf. When the root webpage has visited a page with a form is displayed from this controller.

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class AController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String queryForm(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("query", new Query());
       System.out.println("added query to model");
       return "question_page";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String querySubmit(@ModelAttribute Query query) {
        System.out.println("button pressed");
        return "result";
    }
}
```

The form looks like this. When the form is filled and submit is hit. I would expect that the prior created query is passed from the model the request mapper with a set content. But it seems that is a different query because it has a different memory address.

```
<div clas="queryFrom">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${query}" method="post" 
          class="embed-submit-field">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" id="query" list="suggestions" autocomplete="off"
               class="inputField"/>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" class="btn">
            <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

On the result page is a button which triggers the following request mapper the controller. I expected that the controller would get the same query with the content set, but it gets another query which not content set.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String trigger_reload(@ModelAttribute Query query) {
    System.out.println(query.getContent());  // content is null
    return "result";
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions are welcome.

This question was marked as [possible duplicate of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027801/how-to-set-thymeleaf-thfield-value-from-other-variable). I briefly just wanted to make sure that these questions are completely different. The Content field is set correct from Thymeleaf. The problem is that I did not get the instance of the Query class where the field is set, back from my model. Completely different question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set thymeleaf th:field value from other variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027801/how-to-set-thymeleaf-thfield-value-from-other-variable)

Comment: Sorry it isn't a duplicate of this question.  As i have the problem that i didn't get the same instance of Query back later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. I just needed to add the model attribute to the session otherwise it is lost. I just added `@SessionAttributes({ "query" })` to the top of my class and i solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could approach this method.

Instead of using th:field use html id & name. Set value using th:value

```
<input class="form-control"
           type="text"
           th:value="${content}" id="content" name="content" />
```

Comment: Sorry but this answer did not refer to my question. Just the edited part below of my question ...

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: Yeah i tried it, but as i said your answer even did not refer to the question. The value is correct set in my class, but later i get another instance of this class from memory back!