# Can't use disabled selected with Thyemeleaf th:field

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have Select option and I want to use disable selected for the first option but when I use `th:field` it overrides it and enables the first option.
So I tried to use `th:id`, `th:name`, `th:value` as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027801/how-to-set-thymeleaf-thfield-value-from-other-variable) suggested, but then the select option starts to pickup the last value from the list and ignores the value coming from the model attribute.

Here the code portion:

```
<div class="md-form">
<select name="coordinate" id="coordinate" th:field="*{coordinateSystem}">
    <option value="" disabled selected><label>Choose Coordinate</label></option>
    <option th:each="coordinate : ${data.coordinateSystemList}"
            th:value="${coordinate}"
            th:selected="${data.coordinateSystem}"
            th:text="${coordinate}">
    </option>
</select>
<label class="active" for="coordinate">Coordinate</label>
```

Comment: Try instead of `<option th:each="coordinate : ${data.coordinateSystemList}"
            th:value="${coordinate}"
            th:selected="${data.coordinateSystem}"
            th:text="${coordinate}">
    </option>` this variant: `<th:block th:each="coordinate : ${data.coordinateSystemList}"><option 
            th:value="${coordinate}"
            th:selected="${data.coordinateSystem}"
            th:text="${coordinate}">
    </option> </th:block>` let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Hi @Casper unfortunately it does not work