# th:attr is showing value attribute as empty string

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've got a form where the inputted data gets mapped to the correct variable by using `th:field`. But when the page loads, I want the inputfield to show a default value. So that when the user does not enter any data, the default value gets mapped to the variable.

`th:field` overrides `th:value`, therefore I added: 
`th:attr="value=${field.placeholder}"`, which I found out about in another thread (link in comment), but this doesn't seem to work. When I inspect the element, it shows value as: `value=""`.

I know field.placeholder isn't empty, because `th:placeholder="${field.placeholder}"` does show the value.

```
<form th:action="@{/generateData}" th:object="${stepObject}" method="post" class="form-group">
  <div th:each="field, iterStat : ${stepEntry.value}">
     <label th:text="${field.name}"></label><input type="hidden" th:field="*{name}" th:attr="value=${field.name}"/>

     <input th:type="${field.type}" class="form-control" th:maxLength="${field.length}"
            th:field="*{value}" th:attr="value=${field.placeholder}" th:placeholder="${field.placeholder}"/>

  </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="generateButton">Generate away!</button>
</form>
```

So here in the hidden input it should have the value ${field.name}, but value is "".
in the other input it should have the value ${field.placeholder}, but this value also is "".

Any suggestions on why this is and how I could get this to work?

When I enter data in the inputfields, they get mapped to the value variable of stepObject. But it's important that the user can also just press the button without entering anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This question got me to the th:attr solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027801/how-to-set-thymeleaf-thfield-value-from-other-variable) For him apparently it's working, but not for me.

Comment: Why not set the value in the backing object before getting to the form?

Comment: Because I don't know which step the user will select. In the application you can upload a file and this file contains multiple steps. Each step is basically a seperate form. The user can only select one step at a time to generate data for. I think that if I were to set the value before I get to the form, that would result in alot of data not being used. -- Thanks for the comment though, I'm gonna play around with it anyway! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on using the `th:field` and ended up just using the `@RequestParam("form-name-attribute")` in my controller method to get the (default) value and manually set it to the correct object.

I would've liked to do it with thymeleaf functionality though. 
So if anyone still finds a solution for it, please let me know so I can learn! :-)