# Not pass extra param from controller to template

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

in my spring boot 2 project.

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class CategoryController {
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;

  @RequestMapping("category/add")
    public String addtCategory(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("isAdd", true);
        model.addAttribute("category", new Category());
        return "category";
    }
```

add extra param by this:

```
model.addAttribute("isAdd", true);
```

template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${appName}">Category template title</title>
    <link th:href="@{/public/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="#" th:object="${category}" th:action="@{/category}">
        <h3>Edit Category</h3>
        <input type="hidden" id="isAdd" th:field="${isAdd}"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="id" th:field="*{id}"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" th:field="*{name}"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="created" th:field="*{created}"/>
        <textarea placeholder="Description" rows="5" id="description"
                  th:field="*{description}"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    <div class="result_message" th:if="${submitted}">
        <h3>Your category has been submitted.</h3>
        <p>Find all categories <a href="/categories">here</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and generated html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="/public/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="/category"><input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="5cda30d8-6f11-4e82-bb06-a8eb141afb41"/>
        <h3>Edit Category</h3>
        <input type="hidden" id="isAdd" name="" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="0"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" name="name" value=""/>
        <input type="hidden" id="created" name="created" value=""/>
        <textarea placeholder="Description" rows="5" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see the field:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="isAdd" name="" value=""/>
```

is empty. Why? It must be **true** value

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027801/how-to-set-thymeleaf-thfield-value-from-other-variable

Answer (score 0):

Specify name and value manually (instead of using `th:field`) like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="isAdd"
                   name="isAdd"
                   th:value="${isAdd}"/>
```

Note that this will *not* set up a binding, but I guess that is ok for a hidden field anyway.

Comment: I need than pass this param to controller

Comment: Are you doing this to know if you are adding a new item or editing a known item?

Comment: Yes, this is flag to determine is add category or edit

Comment: What I do for that is using different endpoints. I have `/create` to create and `/<id>` for editing. I do use the same Thymeleaf template, but use that `isAdd` variable to select the correct action endpoint: `th:action="${!isAdd}?@{/category/{id}(id=${category.id})}:@{/category/create}"`