# how can i print Loged in username as input in html page in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring

suppose in my project I am logged in as a ADMIN. I want to pass the ADMIN username to user table throw input in html page. how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give more details when you are asking your question but,
for example, if you use spring boot and thymeleaf, you can read your logged in user details from your authentication with several ways

```
<span sec:authentication="name">Username</span>
```

or

```
<input th:value="${#authentication.name}">
```

or if you want to use in a form

```
<input th:value="${#authentication.name}" th:name="*{fieldName}">
```

Comment: sir when i am using
 <input th:value="${#authentication.name}" th:field="*{pres}"> 
to save the infortamition n database its not showing in page

Comment: sorry for late answer
It's already discussed here you can check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027801/how-to-set-thymeleaf-thfield-value-from-other-variable
Use th:name instead of th:value